# eleminating the records on cross row element

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

```
SRID    Interaction Flag    Flag2   items1                     items2
16222   abc B   4   1852311000001100    19836811000001100
16222   abc B   4   19836811000001100   1852311000001100
18599   abc B   4   1852311000001100    10368611000001100
18599   abc B   4   10368611000001100   1852311000001100
19518   abc A   2   1592311000001100    1852311000001100
19518   abc A   2   1852311000001100    1592311000001100
19518   abc A   2   1852311000001100    19836811000001100
19518   abc A   2   19836811000001100   1852311000001100
```

Hi , Above my result set of complex query. till here i am able to achieve.

please have a look on first 2 records. item1 of 1st row = item2 of 2nd row and vise versa for SRID.if item1 and item2 for SRID is same in any order , i need any one record from itand result should be

```
 SRID    Interaction    Flag    Flag2   items1                     items2
    16222   abc B   4   1852311000001100    19836811000001100
    18599   abc B   4   1852311000001100    10368611000001100
    19518   abc A   2   1852311000001100    1592311000001100
    19518   abc A   2   1852311000001100    19836811000001100
```

Comment: 16222 line2 item1 = 16222 line1 item2 yet the results you show is only affecting the line1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what the rest of the data is like, but this might work....

```
WITH SourceData AS
(
    SELECT
     *
    FROM (  VALUES   (16222, 'abc', 'B', 4, 1852311000001100, 19836811000001100)
                    ,(16222, 'abc', 'B', 4, 19836811000001100, 1852311000001100)
                    ,(18599, 'abc', 'B', 4, 1852311000001100, 10368611000001100)
                    ,(18599, 'abc', 'B', 4, 10368611000001100, 1852311000001100)
                    ,(19518, 'abc', 'A', 2, 1592311000001100, 1852311000001100)
                    ,(19518, 'abc', 'A', 2, 1852311000001100, 1592311000001100)
                    ,(19518, 'abc', 'A', 2, 1852311000001100, 19836811000001100)
                    ,(19518, 'abc', 'A', 2, 19836811000001100, 1852311000001100)) tab(SRID, Interaction, Flag, Flag2, items1, items2)
)
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
     s1.*
    FROM SourceData s1
    JOIN SourceData s2
    ON s1.SRID=s2.SRID
    AND s1.items1=s2.items2
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT
     *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SRID ORDER BY SRID)%2 AS RowID
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
 SRID
,Interaction
,Flag
,Flag2
,items1
,items2
FROM CTE2
WHERE RowID=1;
```